# Группировка и суммирование данных из двух таблиц по уникальному полю

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть условная таблица campaingsTransactions:

```
| rowID | rowCampaignID | rowTimestamp        | rowSpendMoney |
|-------|---------------|---------------------|---------------|
| 1     | 12345         | 2019-07-01 10:00:00 | 200           |
| 2     | 54321         | 2019-07-01 10:00:00 | 150           |
| 3     | 67890         | 2019-07-01 10:00:00 | 270           |
| 4     | 12345         | 2019-07-01 10:30:00 | 500           |
| 5     | 54321         | 2019-07-01 10:30:00 | 220           |
| 6     | 67890         | 2019-07-01 10:30:00 | 100           |
```

И таблица campaingsDescription:

```
| campaignID | campaignCity |
|------------|--------------|
| 12345      | Москва       |
| 54321      | Москва       |
| 67890      | Питер        |
```

Мне нужно вернуть такой ответ:

```
| rowTimestamp        | cityMoskow | cityPiter |
|---------------------|------------|-----------|
| 2019-07-01 10:00:00 | 350        | 270       |
| 2019-07-01 10:30:00 | 720        | 100       |
```

Или нечто похожее. В таблице campaingsTransactions есть три кампании с уникальным ИД (rowCampaignID), которые раз в полчаса добавляются с меткой даты (rowTimestamp) и количеством денег (rowSpendMoney). В таблице campaingsDescription есть столбцы с ИД кампаний и названием города. Результат должен быть сгруппирован по временной метке (rowTimestamp) и показывать общее количество rowSpendMoney для каждого города.

Comment: Типичный PIVOT. В MySQL не реализован - эмулируйте статически либо формируйте структуру динамически.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT rowTimestamp,campaignCity,SUM(rowSpendMoney) rSM
FROM campaingsTransactions cT
LEFT JOIN  campaingsDescription cD on cT.rowCampaignID=cd.rowCampaignID
GROUP BY rowTimestamp,campaignCity;
```

Нечто похожее.